# Problems with if(isset($_GET[]

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have problems with the following script.
I built my website so that the links look like this website.com/contact
Now I want to have a kind of sub pages like website.com/contact/inschrijven or website.com/contact/bouw_aanmelding
But if I have multiple GETS goes wrong. 1 GET everything goes well. What am I doing wrong?

***The codes:***

**Htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^contact/([^/]*) contact.php?tab=$1
```

**PHP code (I've tried so):**

```
<?php    
   if(isset($_GET['tab']) == 'bouw_aanmelding') {
      $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Bouwer worden!";
   }elseif(isset($_GET['tab']) == 'inschrijven') {
      $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Inwoner worden!";
   }elseif(isset($_GET['tab']) == '') {
      $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons";
   }
?>
```

**PHP code (And so):**

```
<?php    
   if(isset($_GET['tab']) == 'bouw_aanmelding') {
       $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Bouwer worden!";
   }
   if(isset($_GET['tab']) == 'inschrijven') {
      $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Inwoner worden!";
   }
   if(isset($_GET['tab']) == '') {
      $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons";
   }
?>
```

Both of the methods have not helped. Hopefully someone can help me here. Thank you.

Ps, Sorry for me bad english, I'm Dutch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`isset`](http://php.net/isset) returns a `boolean`. You should use:

```
 if (isset($_GET['tab']) && $_GET['tab'] == 'inschrijven') {

 }
```

Better yet:

```
$pagetitle = 'default title';

if (isset($_GET['tab'])) {
  switch ($_GET['tab']) {
    case 'bouw_aanmelding':
       $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Bouwner worden!";
       break;
    case 'inschrijven':
       $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Inwoner worden!";
       break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add a default case to the switch and maybe even use a strtolower function

Comment: This solution works only if I request me urls via website.com/contact? tab=bouw_aanmelding I want it also works via website.com/contact/bouw_aanmelding

Comment: @GroundZero case's aren't case sensitive and I set the default above to negate the need for an extra case.

Comment: @Chris try `RewriteRule ^contact/(.*) contact.php?tab=$1`

Comment: @Martin thats not working. I think self that it's something with the htaccess

Comment: @Chris it is, the PHP is fine. I haven't used Apache for a while but this should work: `RewriteRule ^contact/(.+)$ /?tab=$1` -- alternatively, you could just parse the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP

Comment: @Martin I'm now using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and thats works great at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code ..

```
   if(isset($_GET['tab'])){
      if($_GET['tab'] == 'bouw_aanmelding') {
           $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Bouwer worden!";
       }
       if($_GET['tab'] == 'inschrijven') {
          $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons: Inwoner worden!";
       }
       if($_GET['tab'] == '') {
          $pagetitle = "Contacteer ons";
       }
    }else{
        $pagetitle = 'common page title';
    }
```

in your condition isset return true or false and comparing with your value so its mismatch .. you have to write this separately

Comment: You could make the code even shorter, but using 1 if-statement for the isset. See Martin's example

Comment: Also this solution works only if I request me urls via website.com/contact? tab=bouw_aanmelding I want it also works via website.com/contact/bouw_aanmelding

Comment: the add a if statement in true block or use another case on martin suggesion